# Using xampp to run Bugzilla?

Tags: windows-server-2008, xampp, bugzilla

I want to run Bugzilla in xampp on my Windeos server. I searched the net on how to do that but found no real answer. Any experience here? Does it work at all? I also found that Bugzilla installer package ([https://wiki.mozilla.org/Bugzilla%3AWin32Install](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Bugzilla%3aWin32Install)) but I am afraid to run it because it will install Apache as well. Will the xampp Apache and the Bugzilla apache interfere with each other? Is there a good alternative for Bugzilla that runs in xampp?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can install bugzilla on xampp. My own experience (on windows 8.1 pro x64) was using **bzr**. Advantages:

- It does not intall *Apache*
- You can easily upgrade/update it.

You can find more info at [wiki.mozilla.org](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Bugzilla:Win32Install)

Answer (score -3):

You can download the bugzilla folder to your htdocs folder and configure it. For more details you can refer to the online documentation of [Bugzilla](http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/).

Comment: [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include Link to more information and further reading here, and provide the link for reference.